# Get nodeValue for element with specific attribute value

Tags: javascript, xml, get

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<login>
   <status>Login successful</status>
   <ARole10082>Master</ARole10082>
   <IsAdmin10082>True</IsAdmin10082>
   <UserID10082>email@address.com</UserID10082>
   <privilege name="Billing">1</privilege>
   <privilege name="Nag">0</privilege>
   <privilege name="BoardForum">1</privilege>
   <privilege name="Association">1</privilege>
   <privilege name="Security">1</privilege>
   <privilege name="Appearance">1</privilege>
   <privilege name="Configure">1</privilege>
   <privilege name="MerchantAccounts">1</privilege>
</login>
```

I am trying to access the Privilege node value with the name "Security". I am using a jquery $.get() call to call up this xml document. With javascript, how can I access the nodeValue of "1" for "Security" by searching for a node with the Attribute name equal to "Security"?

Comment: What language are you using to access this?

Comment: @Bravo11 I'm using javascript

Comment: .find('[name="Security"]').text()

Answer (score 0):

You can set the received XML string as `innerHTML` of a temporary element, and then query that element (using CSS style selectors) via `document.querySelector()`.

Example ([**online demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/2kUzG/1)):

```js
var xml = '<login>\
   <status>Login successful</status>\
   <ARole10082>Master</ARole10082>\
   <IsAdmin10082>True</IsAdmin10082>\
   <UserID10082>email@address.com</UserID10082>\
   <privilege name="Billing">1</privilege>\
   <privilege name="Nag">0</privilege>\
   <privilege name="BoardForum">1</privilege>\
   <privilege name="Association">1</privilege>\
   <privilege name="Security">1</privilege>\
   <privilege name="Appearance">1</privilege>\
   <privilege name="Configure">1</privilege>\
   <privilege name="MerchantAccounts">1</privilege>\
</login>';
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = xml;

var securityPrivilege =
                 container.querySelector('privilege[name="Security"]').innerHTML;
console.log('securityPrivilege: ', securityPrivilege);
```

Output:

```
securityPrivilege: 1
```

Comment: Did you get to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

Programatically selecting the right node:

```
    public static string GetSecurityValue()
    {
        var document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        document.Load("data.xml");

        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode child in document.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
        {
            // Name is a bad attribut name, child.Name already exists, it will give you status, ARole10082, etc
            if (child.Attributes.Count > 0 && string.Equals("Security", child.Attributes["name"].Value))
            {
                return child.InnerText;
            }
        }

        return "Could not find security node";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var role = x.getElementsByTagName("login");
                    for (i=0; i<role.length; i++){
                        if (role[i].childNodes.length > 3){
                            privileges = role[0].getElementsByTagName("privilege");
                            for (j=0; j<privileges.length; j++){
                                name = privileges[j].attributes.name.value;
                                if (privileges[j].hasChildNodes()){
                                    value = privileges[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                }else{
                                    value = "0";
                                }

                                if (name === "Security" && value === "1"){
                                    localStorage["Security"] = 1;
                                }else{
                                    localStorage["Security"] = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```